# Check listener not being called on checkbox when isChecked set to true

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener, android-checkbox, changelistener

I have a condition where I need to execute the code in `checkChangeListener` directly without clicking on `checkbox`.
I have set the `checkbox.isChecked = true` but still my checkChangeListener is not being called and the code I want to execute isn't being called.
I am not sure, but setting `isChecked=true` should call `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of the `checkBox`.
Also perform click is not working
Can any one please help with this one.

Code:

```kt
if (someCondition) 
{
    checkBox.isChecked = true
}


binding.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    Timber.d("check change called..............................")
    //some code to be executed directly
}


checkBox.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        val isChecked = checkBox.isChecked
        if (isSelectionEnabled || (!isSelectionEnabled && isChecked)) {
            binding.checkBox.isChecked =
            !binding.checkBox.isChecked
        }
    }
    true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute the code in the setOnCheckedChangeListener block without relying on user interaction, you can manually call the listener's code after setting the isChecked property. Here's an example:

```
if (someCondition) {
    binding.checkBox.isChecked = true
    // Manually trigger the listener code
    binding.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        Timber.d("check change called..............................")
        // Some code to be executed directly
    }.onCheckedChanged(binding.checkBox, true)
}
```

Comment: No, it won't work

Comment: then what exactly do you think will?

Comment: Doing it this way doesn’t make sense. Why would you create a new listener just to call it? You could just call that code directly.